# How to plot time series relative to zero?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, math

I have a [time series](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODd4xdQJyx7OTcmw5XpiZGZ39qpz9Gdp/view?usp=sharing) with values ranging from -1 to 1. On the chart, it looks like this:

[image]

Code for image above:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('TimeSeries.csv').set_index('date')
dt_index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(
    axis='x',     
    which='both',     
    bottom=False,
    top=False,
    labelbottom=False)

ax.set_xlim([datetime.date(2022, 3, 1), datetime.date(2022, 4, 15)])
ax.plot(dt_index, df['long'], 'o')
```

I want the chart to look like an oscillator. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djBcj.jpg). From zero to 1/-1 (Now, it is from 1/-1 to zero).

[image]

I believe that the coordinates of the points need to be reflected horizontally relative to zero. But I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: I genuinely do not understand what the desired output is. You say that you currently plot from 1/-1 to 0 but you actually plot from -1 to 1, so it is unclear what the intended inversion is.

Comment: I also don't understand... do you want to plot the absolute value?

Comment: You say that you want your graph to "look like an oscillator" -- but it already does. Are you trying to plot the absolute values of the numbers?

Comment: Can you please also add the code block that generates the plot above (the one you don't want)? So we can check how to convert it to the desired one.

Comment: @mozway I made my question more clear. Please check.

Comment: @JohnColeman I made my question more clear. Please check.

Comment: @AliNaderi I've added code and clarified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing numpy as `import numpy as np`, just substitute the `ax.plot` line with

```
ax.plot(dt_index, df['long']-np.sign(df['long']), 'o')
```

Sample output:

[image]

Explanation: [`np.sign()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) returns elementwise the sign of the number. So, we subtract 1 from positive and add 1 to negative values, centering your values around 0.

Answer (score 0):

**My take:**
I'm not sure what you want the 'oscillation' to look like, because it currently looks like one. However, here's how I handle it:

By iterating over the data points with np.convolve, you can create a function to smooth them. Curve fitting, data smoothing, n-degree polynomials, and even Lowess(the best approach) might all be used in the function. Here's a great [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-smoothing-for-data-science-visualization-the-goldilocks-trio-part-1-867765050615) I found that you can research in order to create your function.

For this case I have done the following way:

```
def smooth(y, data_points):
    plot_point = np.ones(data_points)/data_points
    y_smooth_points = np.convolve(y, plot_point, mode='same')
    return y_smooth_points
```

You could adjust the parameters to define the points on the graph. Following that, I added the data points to a new column and plotted them:

**Here's the complete code for one of the approaches:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


def smooth(y, data_points):
    plot_point = np.ones(data_points)/data_points
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y, plot_point, mode='same')
    return y_smooth

df['smoothen_1']= smooth(df['long'],100)

fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=smooth(df['smoothen_1'],250))
fig.show()
```

**Result:**

[image: Result Image from Plotly Plot]

[image: Readjusting interactive plot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can solve your problem:

```py
# extract values from the dataframe
y = df['long'].values
# select values > 0
idx = y > 0
# offset those values
y[idx] -= 1
# select all other values and apply an opposite offset
y[np.logical_not(idx)] += 1
```

then replace `ax.plot(dt_index, df['long'], 'o')` with `ax.plot(dt_index, y, 'o')`.